# Jenkins ANT scripting: Save file with timestamp

Tags: jenkins, ant, docker

I'm trying to create a **Jenkins job** with target as an **sh** file.
This **sh** file fires up commands on a **Linux VM** to save a **docker image** with **timestamp** in its name.

How do I create a build xml and a properties file for this?
I'm new to Jenkins and ANT scripting.

Can anyone help me with the scripting?
Thanks!

Comment: And why bother doing this in ANT? Setup the Linux VM as a Jenkins slave and then just run a shell based job on the server directly.

Comment: I've done that, However, I'm getting an error in the execute shell build step.
It is unable to run shell scripts placed on the slave.
Does the script needs to be present on the master Jenkins node to run?

Comment: Perhaps the script is not executable?

Comment: I've successfully completed it.
The problem was I was inserting the scripts on the slave machine instead of the master.